# Crashlytics with Android Studio build error

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I'm trying to use CrashLytics with Android Studio and gradle but i get a confusing error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

My build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 18

    //...
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.25'

    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    //compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:2.426.0'

}
```

When trying to `$ gradle assembleDebug`:

```
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices3225Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:crashlyticsCleanupResourcesDebug
:crashlyticsUploadStoredDeobsDebug
:crashlyticsGenerateResourcesDebug
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugResources'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:283)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':mergeDebugResources'
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:527)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)Lcom/android/sdklib/SdkManager;
    at com.android.builder.DefaultSdkParser.initParser(DefaultSdkParser.java:76)
    at com.android.builder.SdkParser$initParser.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.Sdk.loadParser(Sdk.groovy:125)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.Sdk$loadParser.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLoadedSdkParser(BasePlugin.groovy:295)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getAndroidBuilder(BasePlugin.groovy:318)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$getAndroidBuilder.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BaseTask.getBuilder(BaseTask.groovy:29)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources_Decorated.getBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:78)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:136)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:107)
    at org.gradle.util.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:62)
    ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.297 secs
```

I'm not sure why the method is not found, maybe build tools 18 are not supported yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hemal from Crashlytics here!

Can you edit the following line from:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

Should clear it up for ya :)

Comment: I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+' and 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+' the error still exist

Comment: @hemal-shah, I have same problem as xialin. Do you have any suggestion? I have following code in my Gradle: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }

Comment: @Hemal - I am getting this error : Error:Could not find any matches for com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+ as no versions of com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle are available.
All stuff setup from :https://crashlytics.com/downloads/gradle

Answer (score 4):

For all those who have "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0" and "com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+", this is what worked for me:

- Clean project
- Make Project
- Run App

EDIT: If this doesn't work, try to ping download.crashlytics.com and check if they're up. If not just wait till they are.

Comment: In that sort of a case, it's best to try with different connections. Because then it clearly becomes a connection problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case re installing the plugin has solved the issue.

1)
Mac: Select "Preferences…" from the Android Studio Menu.
Windows and Linux: Select "Settings" from the File Menu.

2)Select "Plugins" on the right of the Settings Dialog, uninstall the plugin and restart android studio.

3)Reinstall the plugin and restart android studio.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Clean did not work.  Rebuild did not work.  I could build from the command line, but not from Android Studio.  Finally, I closed Android Studio and deleted build/ and app/build/.  I re-opened Android Studio and the app builds again.