# Gradle Build error with Crashlytics Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, crashlytics

My code was compiling correctly all this while but now I'm suddenly encountering the following error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
> >     Could not resolve com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+.
> >          Required by:
> >              EnergyLens:app:unspecified
> >     Failed to list versions for com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle.
> >     Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/crashlytics/tools/gradle/crashlytics-gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
> >     Could not GET 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/crashlytics/tools/gradle/crashlytics-gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
> >     download.crashlytics.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

This is what my build file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iiitd.muc.energylens"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

I had encountered this problem before; cleaning and rebuilding the project, but I'm getting this error again. Can someone please help me out of this mess and tell me why this problem occurs again and again

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my own question. Since, this happens rather erratically and is in no way connected to my network connection, I believe this occurs because of the crashlythics server being down.

I rebuilt the project the next day and it happened perfectly.

Comment: I believe you're correct about their servers. I didn't even have to wait until the next day. Only about 30 minutes and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your own answer, you can try pinging their servers to see if they're up or not:

```
ping download.crashlytics.com
```

Taken from [Crashlytics with Android Studio build error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945881/3271507)